# Constantly have to run `pulseaduio -k` to make sound work properly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Yesterday I reinstalled the network-manager and since then for some reason audio is acting up. I am using Ubutnu 16.04. I keep getting very bad noise which is resolved by running `pulseaudio -k` but it keeps getting back to the noise so I have to re-run the command. I am connecting through HDMI to a monitor.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is audio in your guest account affected too?

Comment: I didn't check. I can check that.